# AWS EC2 instances communications by security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

So I have two ElasticBeanstalk applications, a master (with load balancer) and a slave (single instance). And I want them to communicate to each other, so I setup security groups the next way:

- master's ELB accepts all HTTP
- master EC2 accepts all HTTP from its ELB (this is assigned by AWS automatically)
- slave accepts HTTP from both master ELB and master EC2

And on the last step something goes wrong - if I allow traffic by EC2 instance's public IP it works like charm. But if I try to do the same by security groups (allow traffic by security group id) it just doesn't let it through.

How I test it - ssh to the master EC2 (where the app is installed) and then send curl to slave's endpoint.

So, any idea what I might be doing wrong? I read tons of documentation and everything looks fine and should just work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Are you curling the slave via its private IP?

Comment: No, by its ElasticBeanstalk url (app_name.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com) which then, I think, resolves to public IP.

Comment: If your app is able to determine the slave's private IP then I'd expect that to work (with the slave's security group allowing inbound from the master's security group). You could use the awscli or EC2 SDK to find the slave's private IP or use some other, private mechanism of sharing that info.

Comment: Ok, I'm able to ping slave's private IP even with all ICMP requests disabled, but public IP is inaccessible until I explicitly allow traffic from master's public IP. The same with pinging slave's URL - when public IP is allowed pings go OK, when disabled - pings don't let through.

Adding security groups rules doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: When you specify the master security group as the source for an ingress rule in the slave security group, this allows instances associated with the master security group to access instances in the slave security group. However, it is important to understand that inbound traffic is allowed based on the **private** IP addresses of the instances that are associated with the source security group. Does this answer your question? If not, please explain what you are still trying to get an answer to.

Comment: The problem is that I don't really understand how I apply this knowledge about private IP address on practice. Because in the end what happens is that master app makes an http request by slave's ElasticBeanstalk url and I don't control the IP address it resolves to. And it doesn't work, when slave's incoming traffic is allowed by master's security group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172606/discussion-between-jarmod-and-konstantin).